# Modify Strings in Table Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that modifies a string from

"evice & Services Help and Troubleshooting: Device Help and Troubleshooting: Device Unlock Code Request 205 613-2860"

to

"Device & Services Help and Troubleshooting Device Help and Troubleshooting Device Unlock Code Request"

This corrects the spelling mistake in the first word, removes the colons and phone number at the end.

I experimented with worksheet functions and the following functions work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE([@Description], ":", " ")

=SUBSTITUTE([@Description], "evice", "Device")

=LEFT([@Description], LEN([@[R-val]])-13)
```

I am having trouble with Error type 13 "Type Mismatch".

I am also assuming that because the original string is in a table that I will not have to do a loop.

My VBA code is

```
Sub rmvstuff()
Dim needsrd As Worksheet
Dim device As String
Dim rmvcln As String
Dim rmvtpnum As String
Dim desc As Range
Dim mycell As String

mycell = ActiveCell.Value



With needsrd
    Set desc = Range("description")
End With

desc.Select
device = WorksheetFunction.Substitute([@Description], "evice", "Device")
rmvcln = WorksheetFunction.Substitute([@Description], ":", " ")
rmvtpnum = WorksheetFunction.Left([@Description], Len([@Description]) - 13)
End Sub
```

I really appreciate any help that I can get on this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors such as `needsrd` is never declared so it's equal to `Nothing`.  Also, `@Description` is not a valid identifier in VBA.

Here is another way to do what your trying:

```
Sub rmvstuff()
    Dim needsrd As Worksheet
    Dim desc As Range

    Set needsrd = Sheets(1)
    Set desc = needsrd.Range("description")

    desc.Value = Replace(desc.Value, "evice", "Device")
    desc.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "DD", "D")
    desc.Value = Replace(desc.Value, ":", "")
    desc.Value = Left(desc.Value, Len(desc.Value) - 13)
End Sub
```

---

Here is how to loop thorugh each cell assuming "description" is a named range of more than one cell:

```
Sub loopRMVstuff()
    Dim needsrd As Worksheet
    Dim desc As Range

    Set needsrd = Sheets(1)
    Set desc = needsrd.Range("description")

    For Each cell In desc
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "evice", "Device")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "DD", "D")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ":", "")
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 13)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

**Tested** using named range for cells `A1:A3`

*Before*
[image]

*After*
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Working on it now. I will let you know how it comes out.

Comment: I edited the post to remove the resulting double 'D'.  There are better ways to do this but I chose a rather simple one for example purposes.